# Node/Express server sees different JSON data between GET and POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, express

I'm writing a Node/Express server and I was switching some of my HTTP verbs around when I noticed something weird with stringified-JSON data between GET and POST.

I'm using $.ajax via jQuery, and here's what the server sees when I switch between POST and GET:

```
// Server call to console.log(req.body) using POST--
{ productIdList: [ '5505e4ecd24efe9f074ecda1' ] }

// Server call to console.log(req.query) using GET--
{ '{"productIdList":': { '"5505e4ecd24efe9f074ecda1"': '' } }
```

The GET case isn't even representing the datatype correctly. What secret am I missing?

Thanks,
PT

EDIT #1

Client JS browser code, send either GET or POST.

```
    data = { productIdList: [ '5505e4ecd24efe9f074ecda1' ];
    :
    :
    // POST mode
    $.ajax('/endpoint', {
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    -- or -- 

    // GET mode
    $.ajax('/endpoint', {
        method: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

Node/express server code

```
router.route('/endpoint')
.get(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
})
.post(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: not quite clear what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

All right I think that, you are looking for a problem where the is none:

You see here:

```
router.route('/endpoint')
.get(function(req, res) {  // <-- res should send the json back
    console.log(req.query);
})
.post(function(req, res) { // <-- req should send the json in
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

To send you must use `buffer` of `string` so you are right to use `JSON.stringify()` on json object. Later use `JSON.parse()` to get the object back.

Note: *HTTP request ( GET ) message is allowed to contain a message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind. Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body, if any, has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements on parsing are separate from the requirements on method semantics.*

Which basically means should not send `JSON` object via Ajax.Get request as body.

The `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` Makes `GET` and `POST` requests handle data differently that's why you are getting parsed POST and `stringified` GET.

For `POST` you are telling what you are sending..

For `GET` the `Content-type` header is helpful but not necessary. You might want to use `accept` header which is a semicolon-separated list of representation schemes ( Content-Type metainformation values) which will be accepted in the response to this request.

eg. `Accept: text/plain, application/json`